# How to extract such text from javascript sentences in a html file by python

Tags: javascript, python, html, package, web-scraping

I'm new to web-scraping coding. I'm using python to parse the html files and the package I'm using is BeautifulSoup. Now I want to extract the certain numbers like the `1` in `$mwidgetHelper.setTitle('Posts (1)')`, the `1` in `$mwidgetHelper.setTitle('Notes (1)')`, and the text like the `user_638166_451203` in `hover_boxes.hoverize_link('user_638166_451203', 'user_profile')` under the `<script>` tag in this html file. The question is I'm not sure which methods I should use to parse these elements. The codes are below:

```
<script>

      newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.id = $mwidgetManager.getTitleId();
      newDiv.className = 'mw_title widget_title ' + $mwidgetManager.getTitleId();
      newDiv.innerHTML = "About Me";
      $p('ppwt_1').appendChild(newDiv);

      $mwidgetHelper.setTitle('About kk');
      $mwidgetManager.nextApp();

      newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.id = $mwidgetManager.getTitleId();
      newDiv.className = 'mw_title widget_title ' + $mwidgetManager.getTitleId();
      newDiv.innerHTML = "Status";
      $p('ppwt_11').appendChild(newDiv);

      $mwidgetHelper.setTitle('Posts (1)');
      $mwidgetHelper.setSubtitle('<a href=\"/user_posts/list/9\">See All<\/a>');
      $mwidgetManager.nextApp();


      $mwidgetHelper.setTitle('Notes (1)');
      $mwidgetHelper.setSubtitle('<a href=\"/notes/list/9\">See All<\/a>');

     //<![CDATA[
          hover_boxes.hoverize_link('user_638166_451203', 'user_profile');
     //]]>

</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your actual question is not very clear.  Please re-phrase.

Comment: @CSJ Thanks for reminding! I have edited my question. Hope it could be clearer~

Comment: This is much better.  A good pattern for asking the question is: (1) Set up the problem, (2) Ask the question, (3) Provide extra details.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beautiful Soup is best used to parse an HTML tree, not JavaScript source code. Looking at the source code, I feel that JavaScript **does** alter the DOM, so you can use Beautiful Soup to scrape the changes in HTML by inspecting the required elements.

EDIT: Here's how to parse the required HTML. Right-click on the element you want to parse in Chrome and select "Inspect Element". The HTML for the corresponding on-screen element should now be highlighted. You can then use the element attributes (id, class etc) to scrape the data using Beautiful Soup.

Hope this helps. If you have further doubts, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to BeautifulSoup so that I'm not sure which methods I could use to parse the text under this script tag. It's not like ordinary tags that I could use get_text() to get the contents. Could you be more specific? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks~ I think I didn't describe my question clearly just now so I edited it :) I have got the whole html file already, and could locate where the elements are in the source. I just don't know how to get into the text under this script tag. Your answer said "use the element attributes (id, class etc) to scrape the data". For my question, does that mean I could only use regular expression to get the data instead of some methods (for example:get('href')) since there are no extra attributes either for the script tag or the text under it. Thanks very much!

Comment: You're misunderstanding what I'm trying to say. I'm saying that you should leave the script alone and focus on the HTML. Try to find elements like Posts (1) on the screen and then inspect that element, not the script tag.